# Creating new column and rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:-

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

print(df)

date        organic         paid        source_type
4/1/2018    39911909.19     38575924.75 Search
4/1/2018    5085939.952     882.608927  Social
4/1/2018    16227439.73     0           Mail
4/1/2018    0               5671871.24  Display Ads
4/1/2018    91215520.23     0           Direct
4/1/2018    15743479.56     0           Referrals
```

I want to add a column total_sum for all the source types except when source type is "Search".
If the source_type is search I want to break down the single row into two and source type becomes organic search and paid search. Inshort a df like below. The summing part is easy to handle i am just stuck with the breaking of rows and conditional column prefix part.
Dataframe I need:-

```
date        source_type     Total Sum
4/1/2018    Organic Search  39911909.19
4/1/2018    Paid Search     38575924.75
4/1/2018    Social          5086822.561
4/1/2018    Mail            16227439.73
4/1/2018    Display Ads     5671871.24
4/1/2018    Direct          91215520.23
4/1/2018    Referrals       15743479.56
```

Comment: What have u tried so far ?

Comment: As i said i can sum it up easily.
df['total_sum'] = df['organic'] + df['paid']
But I am struck with the other part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split DataFrame by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`, then reshape first by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with new column with [`Series.str.capitalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html), filter second by invert mask by `~`, sum values with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove column after and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
mask = df['source_type'].eq('Search')

df1 = df[mask].melt(['date','source_type'], value_name='Total Sum')
df1['source_type'] =  df1.pop('variable').str.capitalize() + ' Search'

df2 = df[~mask].copy()
df2['Total Sum'] = df2.pop('organic').add(df2.pop('paid'))
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print (df)
       date     source_type     Total Sum
0  4/1/2018  Organic Search  3.991191e+07
1  4/1/2018     Paid Search  3.857592e+07
2  4/1/2018          Social  5.086823e+06
3  4/1/2018            Mail  1.622744e+07
4  4/1/2018     Display Ads  5.671871e+06
5  4/1/2018          Direct  9.121552e+07
6  4/1/2018       Referrals  1.574348e+07
```

Comment: this is nice answer.

Comment: this is brilliant thank you!! I was struggling for so much time!